# How to properly use CMake to create a complex project with dependencies on custom libraries

Tags: cmake, linker, shared-libraries, project, static-libraries

I'm trying to create a complex project that becomes a single executable file that uses the following libraries: two libraries BHV and HAL that use one interface library.
I have this project structure:

```
.
├── BHV
│   ├── CMakeCache.txt
│   ├── CMakeFiles
│   ├── cmake_install.cmake
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── include
│   ├── libBHV_Library.so
│   ├── Makefile
│   └── sources
├── HAL
│   ├── check_libraries.cmake
│   ├── CMakeCache.txt
│   ├── CMakeFiles
│   ├── cmake_install.cmake
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── include
│   ├── libHAL_Library.so
│   ├── Makefile
│   └── sources
├── Interface
│   ├── CMakeCache.txt
│   ├── CMakeFiles
│   ├── cmake_install.cmake
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── include
│   ├── libInterface_Library.a
│   ├── Makefile
│   └── sources
├── CMakeCache.txt
├── CMakeFiles
├── cmake_install.cmake
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── main.cpp
├── Makefile
├── README.md
```

Unfortunately, I can't connect the individual libraries to each other.

In Interface_lib CMakeList.txt I have this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Interface_Library)

#requires at least C++17
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)


# Add all .cpp files from sources folder
file(GLOB SOURCES "sources/*.cpp")

# Add all .h files from include folder
file(GLOB HEADERS "include/*.h")

# Add main.cpp to the project
add_library(Interface_Library STATIC ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
```

In HAL_lib CMakeList.txt I have this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(HAL_Library)

# requires at least C++17
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

################################### DIR_MANAGMENT #########################################

# Get the parent directory
get_filename_component(PARENT_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} DIRECTORY)

#Set the directory of the parent file as the current directory
set(CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR ${PARENT_DIR})

message("MYPROJECT_DIR directory: ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}")

################################### HAL_LIB #########################################

# Add all .cpp files from sources folder
file(GLOB SOURCES "sources/*.cpp")

# Add all .h files from include folder
file(GLOB HEADERS "include/*.h")

# Add main.cpp to the project
add_library(HAL_Library SHARED ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})

################################### INTERFACE_LIB #########################################

target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Interface)

# Link the Interface_Library into the HAL_Library
target_link_libraries(HAL_Library Interface_Library)

# check if libraries were included
set(TARGET_NAME HAL_Library)
include(check_libraries.cmake)
```

this is the code i use to check_libraries.cmake (from the internet)

```
# Get a list of referenced libraries
get_target_property(LINK_LIBS ${TARGET_NAME} LINK_LIBRARIES)

# Print the list of referenced libraries
message("Odkazované knihovny: ${LINK_LIBS}")

# Verify that libraries are available on the system
foreach(LIB ${LINK_LIBS})
    execute_process(COMMAND ldd $<TARGET_FILE:${TARGET_NAME}> | grep ${LIB}
                    RESULT_VARIABLE res
                    OUTPUT_QUIET ERROR_QUIET)
    if(res EQUAL "0")
        message("Library ${LIB} was successfully linked with ${TARGET_NAME}")
    else()
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Error: Library ${LIB} not found.")
    endif()
endforeach()
```

As an output I keep getting the library not found. What am I doing wrong?
And is my approach to project structure correct?

Thank you.

Comment: `I keep getting the library not found` Please post the exact message. So what is in ./root/CmakeLists.txt? How ar eyou compiling the project? `Set the directory of the parent file as the current directory` ? What is this supposed to do?

Comment: I strongly recommend not setting up the cmake project in the same directory as the source files. Otherwise you'll end up with cmake-generated dirs+files in the source tree. Furthermore doing so prevents you from setting up 2 separate configurations of the same project in parallel. Instead pass an empty (or even a non-existing dir) as `-B` parameter when doing `cmake ... -S ... -B ...` (propably as replacement for running `cmake .` in the source dir). Btw: show the toplevel `CMakeLists.txt` and at least describe what `HAL/check_libraries.cmake` does.

Comment: Btw: you don't need to specify link dirs for cmake library targets. In fact given the files you've listed doing `target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Interface)` is completely pointless, since there's no directory `HAL/Interface`. Also the use of `file(GLOB)` to collect source files is discouraged; it even says so in [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#glob)

Comment: @KamilCuk As for the other CMakelist.txt, I haven't dealt with it much yet, because I'm primarily dealing with this linking and therefore I'm only working with Interface and HAL CMake. I haven't gotten around to compiling properly yet because it can't logically find the include .h files from the library that can't be loaded.

As for `Set the directory of the parent file as the current directory` it's pasted code from the net that I tried to get into the parent Interface folder because I found out that CMake doesn't support the syntax  ../

Comment: @fabian I added check_libraries.cmake into the question. I know I should specify the build folder, but I didn't want to add more space for error. I'm just trying to figure out how to correctly load my own library, either .a or .so, which is not installed and is located in a parent folder.

Comment: `I'm only working with Interface and HAL CMake` So how are they connected? If you are working on them _separately_ , how should they know to use each other? It should be in the root to `add_subdirectory` both of them. Still, _how_ are you compiling your project? What cmake commands from which directory exactly are you executing? Cmake structure with multiple libraries has been touched in many online tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you do:

```
# ./CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Interface_Library)
add_subdirectory(HAL)
add_subdirectory(Interface)

# HAL/CMakeListst.txt
file(srcs GLOB sources/*.c include/*.h)
add_library(HAL ${srcs})
target_include_directories(HAL PUBLIC include)
target_link_libraries(HAL PUBLIC Interface)

# Interface/CMakeLists.txt
file(srcs GLOB source/*.c include/*.h)
add_library(Interface ${srcs})
target_include_directories(HAL PUBLIC include)
```

That's all. Only *one* `project()` call, in the root. Note the `target_include_directories` missing in your code. Note the main root CMakeLists.txt that includes all. I find `HEADERS` and `SOURCES` separately confusing, I would also use lowercase everything. No `target_link_directories`, CMake will find everything. Also, everything is compiled as one big project, not separately.

Comment: `target_link_directories` I really miss it there. But the way you give the example, individual libraries are actually used in the parent project. But if I want to use one interface library in two independent libraries? And have the possibility of variability in the content of individual libraries?

The goal is actually to separate HAL and BHV to obtain modularity of the project.

Comment: `But if I want to use one interface library in two independent libraries?` Are the libraries independent? This strongly depends _how you_ want to manage dependency. Do you want `HAL`  library to _clone git repository_ of Interface library? Use installed version of Interface library on the system? Recompile the library for itself? There are many solutions here. I like git submodules, but then managing diamond pattern is pain, so I like pyramids. Bottom line, what is an "independent library"? `is actually to separate HAL and BHV` Separate in what way? they are in separate directories.

Comment: If you want to _compile_ only HAL library, you do `cmake --build <dir> --target HAL`. Is this "separation" _you_ want to achieve? CMake OPTION()s allow you to configure the behavior depending on the user defined configuration. My point, _tools_ are there, what do _you_ want to achieve? Another way to look at it, only care if the issue comes up. I showed the typicall CMake construct. From top of my head, take a look at https://github.com/Lora-net/LoRaMac-node for example CMake structure.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll have to think about that architecture a bit more and look for more knowledge. Last question, if I were to apply the solution proposed by you and I wanted to implement the .h file from Interface in HAL/include, I would have to use, for example, this notation `#include "../../Interface/include/xy.h"`. Is this the right approach? (doesn't seem like much to me)

Comment: `target_include_directories` adds the directory to include paths. If you do `target_include_directories(.... include)` than the include dir in the directory CMakeLists.txt is in, that directory is added include search paths. If there is `xy.h` file in that directory, you would just `#include <xy.h>`. `#include ""` notation searches starting from the same directory the currently processed file is in, so for files from compiler search paths prefer `<>`. This is only rather to what `target_include_directories` do you exactly add.